# Adding records in Many-to-Many relation cause duplicate error in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I have 2 tables: `Book`, `Author` and secondary table `books_authors` and similar to this code:

```
book=Book()
for author in authors:
     a = Author()
     a.books.append(book)
     session.merge(a) #1

session.merge(book) #2
session.commit()
```

This code cause a error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: 
(IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '1234' for key 'id'") 
'INSERT INTO `Book` (title, id)  VALUES (%s, %s)' ('test', u'1234')
```

I guess this is because merge is made twice (#1, #2).

So I decided remove `#1`. Errors not occurs, however nothing appears in table Author.
When I decided remove `#2`, tables Book, Author and books_authors where fill in correctly, as long as only one author was added to book.

More authors causes simillar as previous error.

Is it normal that `#2` merge don't merge added authors? Is it only works in one direction? If yes, how to not duplicate book entry by merging two author entries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your application code, but the gist of what you are attempting should go like this:

Insert the book record, if it's not already there.

Insert the author record, if it's not already there.

Insert the book_authors record if it's not already there.

To prevent duplicate entries, use this type of syntax.

```
insert into yourtable
(field1, field2, etc)
select distinct value1, value2, etc
from some_small_table
where not exists
(subquery to check for existing records)
```

Depending on your database engine, the from some_small_table part might not be necessary.